# How to set zsh $RPROMPT from parent bash

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a file that customize the rprompt like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Environment ....
export PATH="/some/path/:$PATH"
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/a/really/nice/path"

# Tell the user we are in the environment
export RPROMPT="BUILD ENV - $RPROMPT"

echo "********* Entering build environnment *******"
$SHELL
echo "********* Exiting build environment *********"
```

But it doesn't work. `$SHELL` is zsh. How can I set the `$RPROMPT` variable from a parent bash script without having to modify the user configuration files? (`.zsh`, `.bashrc`...)

I can't use zsh in the parent script in case of the user doesn't have zsh. But if he has zsh, it should add this optional feature to modify the prompt.

Comment: Should work fine. Are you sure there isn't a configuration file that's resetting `RPROMPT` regardless of what might be found in the environment?

Comment: Yes, the `.zshrc` modify probably the `RPROMPT` because I use custom themes with oh-my-zsh. The `RPROMPT` variable is probably overwritten. Is it possible in this case?

Comment: Not really; the value you add to the environment is immediately overwritten by the configuration files. You could try to unset the `RCS` and `GLOBAL_RCS` options when you start the shell, but even that can be overridden by /etc/zshenv, which is the only configuration file you *cannot* prevent from being sourced.

Comment: Ultimately, shell configuration is under the control of the user. You can export something like `build_prompt_label="BUILD_ENV  - "`, then *suggest* to a user that they add this to their RPROMPT.

Comment: I don't understand why you mention here _bash_  **and** _zsh_. Please focus on **one** shell in a question. In theory, if you have a variable which should be set the **same** in bash and zsh, you would define it in some file (say `~/.sh_common`) and source this file from, i.e., .bashrc and .zshrc. With RPROMPT, this approach does not make sense of course, because prompting syntax is different in bash and zsh.

Comment: @user1934428 The question focus on two shells. Both are related. Just read the question. By the way the solution is just to *suggest* the user to add to their shell. It is not perfect but it works. Ideally I would like something like venv prefix in prompt.

Comment: Yes, but RPROMPT in bash is not compatible to RPROMPT in zsh. They simply are named the same. If the question would be: "How can we make an arbirtrary variable the same content in bash and zsh", I can accept it (and you would use the solution I have outlined in my comment), but with special, incompatible variables, it does not make sense.

Comment: I did not known that bash used the RPROMPT variable. Isn't it just an environment variable?